# ASP.NET click on button doesn't work in code behind

Tags: html, asp.net

Here's the deal, I making a website that sells some products and according to how much products, I have the amount of buttons changes too.

For example if I have 5 products I have 5 buttons, something like this:

[image: Picture]

So i wrote a code which looks like this:

```
            SqlHey SQLViewProducts = new SqlHey();
            DataSet DSViewProducts = new DataSet();
            string Sheilta = "SELECT TblShop.ItemName, TblShop.Price, TblShop.ShopType, TblShop.Image, TblShop.Description FROM TblShop;";
            DSViewProducts = SQLViewProducts.chkData(Sheilta);
            int I;
            for (I = 0; I < DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows.Count; I++)
            {
                if (DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows.Count % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if (I % 2 == 0)
                        CatalogProducts.InnerHtml += " <div class=\"row\"> <div style=\"position: relative\" class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-1 animated bounceInLeft\"> <div class=\"hovereffect\"> <img class=\"img-responsive\" src= \".." + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][3].ToString() + "\"" + " alt=\"\"> <div class=\"overlay\"> <h2>Add to cart<span style=\"font-size: 0.65em\"></span> <asp:Button ID=\"Button1\" runat=\"server\" BackColor=\"Transparent\" BorderStyle=\"None\" ForeColor=\"Transparent\" Height=\"43px\" Style=Height=\"z-index: 99; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px\" Text=\"a\" Width=\"87px\" /></h2> <p class=\"icon-links\">" + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][0].ToString() + "<br /> " + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][4].ToString() + " </p> </div> </div> </div>";
                    else CatalogProducts.InnerHtml += " <div style=\"position: relative\" class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-1 animated bounceInLeft\"> <div class=\"hovereffect\"> <img class=\"img-responsive\" src= \".." + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][3].ToString() + "\"" + " alt=\"\"> <div class=\"overlay\"> <h2>Add to cart<span style=\"font-size: 0.65em\"></span> <asp:Button ID=\"Button1\" runat=\"server\" BackColor=\"Transparent\" BorderStyle=\"None\" ForeColor=\"Transparent\" Height=\"43px\" Style=\"z-index: 99; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px\" Text=\"a\" Width=\"87px\" /></h2> <p class=\"icon-links\">" + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][0].ToString() + "<br /> " + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][4].ToString() + " </p> </div> </div> </div> </div> <br /> <br />";
                }

                if (DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows.Count % 2 != 0)
                {
                    if (I + 1 == DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                        CatalogProducts.InnerHtml += " <div class=\"row\"> <div style=\"position: relative\" class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-1 animated bounceInLeft\"> <div class=\"hovereffect\"> <img class=\"img-responsive\" src= \".." + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][3].ToString() + "\"" + " alt=\"\"> <div class=\"overlay\"> <h2>Add to cart<span style=\"font-size: 0.65em\"></span> <asp:Button ID=\"Button1\" runat=\"server\" BackColor=\"Transparent\" BorderStyle=\"None\" ForeColor=\"Transparent\" Height=\"43px\" Style=Height=\"z-index: 99; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px\" Text=\"a\" Width=\"87px\" /></h2> <p class=\"icon-links\">" + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][0].ToString() + "<br /> " + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][4].ToString() + " </p> </div> </div> </div> </div> ";
                    if (I % 2 == 0)
                        CatalogProducts.InnerHtml += " <div class=\"row\"> <div style=\"position: relative\" class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-1 animated bounceInLeft\"> <div class=\"hovereffect\"> <img class=\"img-responsive\" src= \".." + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][3].ToString() + "\"" + " alt=\"\"> <div class=\"overlay\"> <h2>Add to cart<span style=\"font-size: 0.65em\"></span> <asp:Button ID=\"Button1\" runat=\"server\" BackColor=\"Transparent\" BorderStyle=\"None\" ForeColor=\"Transparent\" Height=\"43px\" Style=Height=\"z-index: 99; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px\" Text=\"a\" Width=\"87px\" /></h2> <p class=\"icon-links\">" + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][0].ToString() + "<br /> " + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][4].ToString() + " </p> </div> </div> </div> </div> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />";
                    else CatalogProducts.InnerHtml += " <div style=\"position: relative\" class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-1 animated bounceInLeft\"> <div class=\"hovereffect\"> <img class=\"img-responsive\" src= \".." + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][3].ToString() + "\"" + " alt=\"\"> <div class=\"overlay\"> <h2>Add to cart<span style=\"font-size: 0.65em\"></span> <asp:Button ID=\"Button1\" runat=\"server\" BackColor=\"Transparent\" BorderStyle=\"None\" ForeColor=\"Transparent\" Height=\"43px\" Style=Height=\"z-index: 99; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px\" Text=\"a\" Width=\"87px\" /></h2> <p class=\"icon-links\">" + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][0].ToString() + "<br /> " + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][4].ToString() + " </p> </div> </div> </div> </div> <br /> <br />";
                }
            }


           protected void Allbuttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
                string BTNID = ((Button)sender).ID.ToString();
                Session["ItemName"] = BTNID;
                Response.Redirect("ViewItem.aspx");
           }
```

But the button doesn't work when I click it. I wrote the same code (the div one) on HTML to see maybe, I did something wrong and the buttons do work!

This is how it's looks like when I wrote it on HTML (That is working):

```
<div class="row">

   <div style="position: relative" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-1 animated bounceInLeft">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="../User/Pictures/ShirtCheck.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>Add to cart<span style="font-size: 0.65em"></span>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None"
                        ForeColor="Transparent" Height="43px" Style="z-index: 99; left: 0px; position: absolute;
                        top: 0px" Text="a" Width="87px" />
                <p class="icon-links"></p>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Why when I write it manually the button does work and when I do it by code behind they don't?**

Comment: **Unsolicited advice:** Consider using CSS classes rather than inline styles, and using CSS to add space between elements rather than line breaks. You might also look into using `StringBuilder` rather than concatenating strings in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic example, but it can apply to what you're doing in your application. Okay so suppose you have a data source like this:

```
 protected List<string> ListOfStrings { get; set; }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListOfStrings == null)
                ListOfStrings = new List<string>();

            ListOfStrings.Insert(0, "First item");
            ListOfStrings.Insert(1, "Second item");
            ListOfStrings.Insert(2, "Third item");
            ListOfStrings.Insert(3, "Fourth item");
        }
```

This data source are your products... I saw that you're generating your HTML for the ASPX page in code behind, which is generally considered a bad practice nowdays since you want your HTML and C# code to be implemented completely separated (this is the purpose of this answer). What you can do to separate your HTML and C# is to use the binding expression in your ASPX page like following:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% for (int i = 0; i < ListOfStrings.Count(); i++)
       {

    %>
       <p><%=ListOfStrings[i] %></p>
    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

This way you are completely separating the HTML from the C# code itself and it is much easier for you to handle the HTML later on if you need to make changes in the HTML itself, rather than modifying the C# code (which I think is a pain in the ass)... So always try to separate your code from HTML, that is a good practice. Hope this helps you out.. :)